# Filter array for multiple values and limit the result

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have an array with multiple objects:

```
export class Task {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  state: number;
  priority: number;
  desc: string;
  date: string;
  listid: string;
}
```

**How can I filter this array for the first five tasks with the closest upcoming dates?** Furthermore, there's the possibility that an object's date is empty - **in case there aren't at least five tasks with dates**, the remaining amount of tasks shall be replaced with tasks sorted by their priority (5 high - 1 low).

F.e. for the following array (I ignored the less important values) ..

```
tasks = [
  { date: 19-07-2019, priority: 2 },
  { date: 21-07-2019, priority: 3 },
  { date: 20-07-2019, priority: 4 },
  { date: null, priority: 2 },
  { date: null, priority: 4 },
  { date: null, priority: 5 },
  { date: null, priority: 3 }
  ];
```

**.. I want the function to return this:**

```
result = [
  { date: 19-07-2019, priority: 2 },
  { date: 20-07-2019, priority: 4 },
  { date: 21-07-2019, priority: 3 },
  { date: null, priority: 5 },
  { date: null, priority: 4 },
];
```

I've already tried figure a way out, but that's all I've got:

```
getFirstFiveTasks(): Observable<Task[]> {
    return of(this.tasks.filter(tasks => tasks.date > this.date));
}
```

But this one solely returns the tasks with upcoming date, doesn't limit the result to 5 and ignores the priority in case there would be tasks without dates.

Comment: Order by date, then priority (if dates are equal), and `slice(0, 5)` on the output?

Comment: How do I order by date and then append those without sorted by priority? Date shall always come first and only if there aren't 5 with date, tasks sorted by priority shall be appended.

Comment: I really wouldn' t care if date is null or not, if you sort by closest, and by priority, it should create the correct order for you to take the first 5 items of the array ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are several things you could work on in this case. I created a snippet in JavaScript, so it shouldn't be a huge hassle to transform it to typescript.

Before all of this, I did have to update your `Date` strings, as I couldn't parse them originally with [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), however, I assume you have the dates as real dates in your code so you could ignore my parsing when I am using it.

So to order, on more than 1 criteria, you could order like:

```
function compareTasks( t1, t2 ) {
  // if dates are equal, priority wins
  if (t1.date === t2.date) {
    return t2.priority - t1.priority;
  }
  // if either is null, the other one wins
  if (t1.date === null && t2.date !== null) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (t1.date !== null && t2.date === null) {
    return -1;
  }
  // otherwise, the closest date wins
  return Date.parse(t1.date) - Date.parse(t2.date);
}
```

Once you have that, you just sort your array (take a slice of it first, so you don't mutate it), and then take the first n items.

```
function orderBy( array, ordercb ) {
  // slice() creates a copy, then sorts on that copy, returning the ordered copy
  // there is no mutation of the input parameter
  return array.slice().sort( ordercb );
}

function take( array, count ) {
  // take the first count items
  return array.slice( 0, count );
}
```

```js
const tasks = [
  { date: '2019-07-19', priority: 2 },
  { date: '2019-07-21', priority: 3 },
  { date: '2019-07-20', priority: 4 },
  { date: null, priority: 2 },
  { date: null, priority: 4 },
  { date: null, priority: 5 },
  { date: null, priority: 3 }
];

function orderBy( array, ordercb ) {
  return array.slice().sort( ordercb );
}

function take( array, count ) {
  return array.slice( 0, count );
}

function compareTasks( t1, t2 ) {
  if (t1.date === t2.date) {
    return t2.priority - t1.priority;
  }
  if (t1.date === null && t2.date !== null) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (t1.date !== null && t2.date === null) {
    return -1;
  }
  return Date.parse(t1.date) - Date.parse(t2.date);
}

console.log( take( orderBy( tasks, compareTasks ), 5 ) );
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I exclude already passed dates? Because right now a task with f.e. the 10th July is being displayed as well, but only upcoming should.

Comment: @Tim just filter them out before sorting, using the `Array.filter` method :)

Comment: I used `return array.filter( tasks => tasks.date >= this.date);`, but this also removed the null date tasks.